# window.dialogarguments not working in chrome

Tags: javascript

I am passing an address object from an aspx page to a modal window using `window.showModalDialog` and validating the address using a JavaScript call by using `window.dialogarguements` and passing the address back to the aspx page. This is all working fine till now using IE11, Now it is not working in MS edge and chrome. I tried replacing `window.showModalDialog` with `window.open` and it is saying `undefined` and not validating the address.

here is my code in parent page:

```
dialogWin = window.open('url', obj, "dialogwidth: 700px; dialogheight: 700px; resizable: no;");
```

in JavaScript:

```
var inputAddress = window.dialogarguements;
```

Comment: A pop-up window doesn't send arguments back to main window. You've to assign a value to a global variable of the opener window in the pop-up. Use `window.opener` to get a reference to the main window. See also [`window.open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) for correct third argument of the method.

Comment: Note that `showModalDialog` has been deprecated for a long time. See [MDN's page on it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog). It was removed completely in Chrome 43.